# How do I correctly (or better) define this bound or constraint in the padic ring $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, collatz-conjecture

Let $T(x)$ be a partial function $:\mathcal P(\Bbb Z^+)\to\Bbb Z_2$.

I have the rule for a certain $\underline x\in \mathcal P(\Bbb Z^+)$ that at least every fourth digit of $T(\underline x)$ is a $1$ (for the avoidance of doubt, there is no infinitely repeating sequence of zeroes and no sequence of more than three zeroes in a row).

Then for every other $x$ on which the function is defined, $T(x)$ has more zeroes than $\underline x$.

> How do I write this condition as a rule or constraint in $\Bbb Z_2$?

I want to write something like $T(x)\leq-\frac1{15}$ for all $x\in\mathcal P(\Bbb Z^+)$.  This usage of $\leq$ is derived from the natural ordering of the subset of $\Bbb Q$ that naturally embeds in $\Bbb Z_2$.  Have I translated the rule into a bound correctly, and are there alternative or better ways of representing this bound?

I'm happy to accept a bound or rule that's valid only on the subset of $\Bbb Q$ that embeds in $\Bbb Z_2$

Background FWIW: This relates to a lower bound on the path the Collatz graph takes through the positive integers.

Comment: I don't understand your "digits" conditions. $\Bbb{Z}_2 = \{ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 2^n, a_n \in \{0,1\}\}$. And $\le $ is exactly what doesn't extend to  $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @reuns by digits I'm referring to its binary representation so $\overline{0001}_2$ complies and $\overline{00001}_2$ doesn't.  Seen as elements of $\Bbb Q$ embedded in $\Bbb Z_2$ these numbers are $-\frac1{15}$ and $-\frac1{31}$. Since large parts of $\Bbb Q$ embed in $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\leq$ works on $\Bbb Q$ it should hopefully be clear what I've cobbled together.  I'm asking how it should be done properly!

Comment: @reuns apologies if I misled you.  The positive integers are neither here nor there really in respect of this question. The preimage of $T$ just happens to be a subset of the powerset of the positive integers but $T(x)$ is firmly in $\Bbb Z_2$, seen as infinitely long strings drawn from $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: That's what my comment is about, $y=T(x)$. I realize I copied my comment uncorrectly : $y\in \Bbb{Z}_2$ has a 2-adic expansion $y=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n 2^n, a_n \in \{0,1\},N \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \cup \infty$ **with finitely many zeros** iff $y \in \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: @reuns p.s. it's probably a minor oversight but to prevent any misunderstanding, you mentioned *fewer than three zeroes*, but the condition in the question is much weaker. The question concerns elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ having fewer than three *consecutive* zeroes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $...001001001001010_2 = \frac{6}{7}$ is of the kind you describe. So you want to declare $6/7 \le -1/15$? Not fair (and not "derived from", because not compatible with, the archimedean ordering on $\mathbb Q \cap \mathbb Z_2$).

Comment: Thank-you @TorstenSchoeneberg.  I guess I can also have simple counterexamples like $1-\frac1{15}$ which fulfils the rules but is above the bound. There must surely be a way of writing or understanding the rule though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is that $y\in \Bbb{Z}_2$ has a 2-adic expansion $$y=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n 2^n, a_n \in \{0,1\},N \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \cup \infty$$ with finitely many zeros iff $y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

> (proof : or $N$ is finite or the series is up to finitely many terms $\sum_{n=N}^\infty 2^n = -2^N$)

$\Bbb{Q} \cap \Bbb{Z}_2 = \{ \frac{u}v, u,v\in \Bbb{Z}, 2 \nmid v\}$

Having at least 3 zeros is restrictive only on $\Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{Z}_2 $ but it doesn't translate to a $\ge$ condition.

And the condition " no sequence of more than three zeroes in a row" is exactly what doesn't have any easy meaning in $\Bbb{Z}_2$.